# Get data from ArrayList inside method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, collections, arraylist

I have an ArrayList item that holds Objects

```
ArrayList<Object> nodeList;
```

I fill it with records I retrieve form database like this

```
//start loop
nodeList.add(getResultSet().getString(i).trim());
//end loop
```

Now, I want to get those results, so I create a "getter" method

```
public Object getResults(){
    for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++){
        return nodeList.get(i);
    }
}
```

Netbeans tells me that return statement is missing, although I return every single object of the arrayList inside loop. How am I supposed to fix it? I tried to return an Array of Objects but it didn't work either. It's still in a loop an it wants to return something outside loop. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if nodeList.size() returns 0? Then the for loop will never run and nothing will be returned so you need a return statement after the for loop

Comment: The method will return just the first object and not the others.

Comment: If you're only storing `String`s in your `List`, then change the type declaration to `List<String>` instead.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually I want to use it for every type of data -String, int etc. What if I cast that objects?

Comment: You should not store the data in a `List<Object>`, instead create an entity with the desired fields and fill each field in a class instance.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I am now studying about generics. Could that entity you're talking about be a generic method, or it's not a good idea?

Comment: It could be depending on your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Netbeans is complaining because, if the list is empty, the code will not enter the `for` loop body and no value is ever returned.

Also your getter method makes no sense. You are always returning the first element in the list because `return` will exit the method. If you "want to get those results", you should just return the whole `nodeList`.

```
public List<Object> getResults() {
   return nodeList;
}
```

If you want to get element at index `i`, you would write the getter as follows:

```
public Object getResult(int i) {
   return nodeList.get(i);
}
```

Also, as pointed out by Luiggi in comments, you could avoid adding the results in a list of `Object`s and instead create an entity class with fields corresponding to the retrieved columns.

Comment: manouti & @Evgeny Makarov thank you so much about your solution. It works now and I get data the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get to return command, method finished. You getting error because in case you will provide empty list as method argument, the for loop will be ignored and method should return something in this case.

If you want to return some value from list, you should write something like:

```
public Object getResults(int position){
        return nodeList.get(position);
}
```